# How to cache view files into file.html on codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, caching

I intend to save all views files generated by Codeigniter on my desktop; I need to output the views into files like home.html, single.html, page.html inside a folder. Is there an solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you might return a view as data, simply assign it to a variable.

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', $data, true);
```

Just get this response, create a file and upload to the server (using either fwrite or ftp).

Below a quick example:

```
<?php
$file = '/var/www/whatever/upload_dir/file.html';
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', $data, true);
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $string );
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the view and have it returned as a string by supplying a third parameter (boolean `TRUE`) while calling [`$this->load->view()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html). From there, you can call [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write the string into a file.

```
$view_string = $this->load->view('some_view', '', TRUE);
file_put_contents('filename', $view_string);
```

You can also use `write_file()` supplied by [CodeIgniter File Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) to write the string to a file.